# character encoding error not resolved by specifying encoding

Tags: r, character-encoding, web-scraping, xml-parsing

I am trying to extract text from a Spanish-language source in R, and running into a character encoding problem which is not resolved by explicitly specifying the encoding within `htmlParse`, as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064096/encoding-issue-in-r-htmlparse-xml).

```
library(XML)
library(httr)
url <- "http://www3.hcdn.gov.ar//folio-cgi-bin/om_isapi.dll?E1=&E11=&E12=&E13=&E14=&E15=&E16=&E17=&E18=&E2=&E3=&E5=ley&E6=&E7=&E9=&headingswithhits=on&infobase=proy.nfo&querytemplate=Consulta%20de%20Proyectos%20Parlamentarios&record={4EBB}&recordswithhits=on&softpage=Document42&submit=ejecutar%20"
doc <- htmlParse(rawToChar(GET(url)$content),encoding="windows-1252")
text <- xpathSApply(doc, "//text()[not(ancestor::script)][not(ancestor::style)][not(ancestor::noscript)][not(ancestor::form)]", xmlValue)
text[77]
```

The 77th element, which includes an accented i, has the offending characters.  The fourth line has some additional hoops I have to jump through to read this source.  The document itself claims to be encoded in "windows-1252."  Specifying "latin1" and several other encodings I have tried are no better.  In my actual application, I have already downloaded many of these files and am reading them locally using `readLines`...and I can tell that the error is not present after reading the file into R, so the problem must be in `htmlParse`.  Also, just accepting the encoding error and correcting it ex post does not seem to be an option, as R does not even recognize the characters it is spitting out if I try to copy and paste them back into a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick fix that may work after you bring the file into R

```
Encoding(text) <- "UTF-8"
```

Changing the coding to "UTF-8" makes Spanish files a lot more usable.